# How do you pass file_system_blacklist arg to Datadog Docker Agent run command?

Tags: docker, datadog

I want to exclude a path to avoid getting my logs spammed like so:

```
 (disk.py:75) | Unable to get disk metrics for /host/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc:
  [Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links: 
    '/host/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc'\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2020-03-12T23:01:38.424330408Z"}
```

I'm running datadog as a docker agent using the command here:
https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/docker/?tab=standard#installation

how do I specify files to exclude in the docker run command? is it an environment variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer here:
https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/issues/3329#issuecomment-595946341

The field is called `mount_point_blacklist`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the warning, you can try adding `none` and `shm` to the `excluded_filesystems` in disk.yaml.  This file should exist or be created in the Agent's conf.d directory.

Otherwise, you'll find more options [here](https://github.com/DataDog/dd-agent/issues/2932).

If you are looking to exclude the logs from the agent within the platform you can look at excluding the agent ([doc](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/autodiscovery/management/?tab=containerizedagent#exclude-containers))